# detect if headset is plugged in in iPhone/iPod

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I detect if the headset is connected to an iPod/iPhone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programatically detect earpiece in iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832041/how-to-programatically-detect-earpiece-in-iphone)

Answer (score 3):

[How to programmatically detect earpiece in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832041/how-to-programatically-detect-earpiece-in-iphone)

Google it.

Note: Why would someone vote this down?

Comment: Maybe because your answer sounds kind of rude. Google it.

Comment: Probably because of the way you answered it.  Probably.

Comment: I will take note to write seventy paragraphs of friendly banter the next time when I'm answering a question.

Comment: +1 for making a fair point. A lot of questions could be avoided if people could just be bothered to try and find the solution by themselves