# In iPhone, to support bluetooth headphone, do I have to do something?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, headphones

I'm developing music app.

I did nothing to support normal wired headphone or headset but I can hear music with my headphones.

Do I have to write some code to support bluetooth headphone or bluetooth headset?

Do I have to buy bluetooth headphone to check it works?

**EDIT**

Sorry, I did something to support wired headphone.
I wrote code to detect the event that headphone unpluged.
And when headphone unpluged, my music app paused.
Does this code work for bluetooth headphone, too?

I'm using the same code as **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832449/709950)** to detect unpluged-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should normally work, without writing.
Maybe you can ask on facebook for someone to test it.
But it should work

Comment: thanks for answer. I've added **EDIT** to my question. Please take a look if you don't mind.

Comment: I have no idea, but you van Allah's send me the app to test it