# Iphone and Ipod touch share the same SDK?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

Means all the applications on the apple store can be both used in iphone and ipod touch, is it right?

Comment: This is a duplicate of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128245/ipod-touch-compared-to-iphone-as-development-platform-for-iphone-apps , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899651/iphone-apps-running-on-ipod-touch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes. app store applications are compatible with both the devices.