# check whether headphones are plugged in when app starts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, headphones

I'm sorry about asking this question which is discussed here many times once again. But none of the answers haven't really helped me. All I need is to put some simple code in a `viewDidLoad` to check whether the headphones are plugged in or are not. (If they aren't I want to pop up simple message, but that's not what I'm asking how to do.) Any help?

Comment: This is a great question! Thanks for asking, it's interesting to learn the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should achieve what you want (iOS 6+ compatible)

```
- (BOOL)areHeadphonesPluggedIn {
    NSArray *availableOutputs = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] currentRoute].outputs;
    for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription *portDescription in availableOutputs) {
        if ([portDescription.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Worked great! thank you. Anyway is there any other solution for older iOS?

Comment: I haven't tried, but there are several threads about it. This is one example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685313/detecting-if-headset-are-plugged-into-ios-device

Comment: thanks, this works in iOS9. There are a number of older strings discussing this topic but they seem out of date.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Swift 1.2 Version of the code written by Gabriele Petronella

```
//This method checks if headphones are plugged in.

func areHeadphonesPluggedIn()->Bool
{
    var availableOutputs = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute.outputs
    for portDescription in availableOutputs
    {
        if portDescription.portType == AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones
        {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```