# How do I check if the iPod supports audio recording?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-audio, ipod

How do I check if the iPod supports audio recording using Cocoa API?

Comment: AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);    
UInt32 propertySize, micConnected;
    AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioInputAvailable, &propertySize, &micConnected);
    [self updateMicStatus:micConnected]; // user-created method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what devices support audio recording (iPhone always does for example) you can use methods from this question:

[Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk)

Actual testing for input device connected can be done by Audio Session Services shown in this solution:

[Detecting iPhone/iPod Touch Accessories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667196/detecting-iphone-ipod-touch-accessories)

Comment: my ipod touch (2g) supports audio recording if a headset with microphone is plugged in. So I would not go for the method you suggest.

Comment: Well, the thing is iPods can have audio input if you plug in specific headphones...

Comment: Ah this seems to have the answer to checking for actual connected input devices:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667196/detecting-iphone-ipod-touch-accessories