# What information does an iphone app have about the handset?

Tags: iphone, uidevice, handset

Our app has a 'contact us' section, from which the user can dial our call centre.  At the moment it goes through to our switchboard.  We'd like to provide them with a few buttons which would route the user to the right department, but we only have one external number.  We're thinking about writing a service so that the app could hit an API to register the department that the user has selected before it opens the call URL.  Then when the call comes through, a plugin for the call centre software can look up to see whether the user has registered a department, and put them straight through if they have.

The problem is - what can we pass to the API that we can recognise later?  We don't have the phone number in the app (or do we?) and we don't have a device ID when we're the callee.  I know there's a [UIDevice class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) but there's also some info that you can pull from the address book.  Is there a full list anywhere of all the information that an app has about the handset?

Comment: You might be interested in this Area 51 proposal on Jailbreaking development http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18154/ios-jailbreaking-development?referrer=EuWVi6IpN0_KzzEhC7I-Qw2

Comment: see of this helps.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667196/detecting-iphone-ipod-touch-accessories

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to just use exensions (phone_number,extension) in order to let your call centre software route the call to the appropiate department. Phone information is really unreliable (some owners/devices/networks might block caller id).